# How to pass a parameter to only one part of a pipeline object in scikit learn?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pipeline

I need to pass a parameter, `sample_weight`, to my `RandomForestClassifier` like so:

```
X = np.array([[2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 3.0,
        2.0, '0'],
       [15.0, 2.0, 5.0, 5.0, 0.466666666667, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        7.0, 14.0, 2.0, '0'],
       [3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.33333333333, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        9.0, 8.0, 2.0, '0'],
       [3.0, 2.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.666666666667, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        5.0, 3.0, 1.0, '0']], dtype=object)

y = np.array([ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.])

m = sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(
        random_state=0, 
        oob_score=True, 
        n_estimators=100,
        min_samples_leaf=5, 
        max_depth=10)

m.fit(X, y, sample_weight=np.array([3,4,2,3]))
```

The above code works perfectly fine.  Then, I try to do this in a pipeline object like so, using pipeline object instead of only random forest:

```
m = sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline([
    ('feature_selection', sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest(
        score_func=sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression,
        k=25)),
    ('model', sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(
        random_state=0, 
        oob_score=True, 
        n_estimators=500,
        min_samples_leaf=5, 
        max_depth=10))])

m.fit(X, y, sample_weight=np.array([3,4,2,3]))
```

Now this breaks in the `fit` method with "`ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`".

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-212-c4299f5b3008> in <module>()
     25         max_depth=10))])
     26 
---> 27 m.fit(X, y, sample_weights=np.array([3,4,2,3]))

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.pyc in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    128         data, then fit the transformed data using the final estimator.
    129         """
--> 130         Xt, fit_params = self._pre_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    131         self.steps[-1][-1].fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)
    132         return self

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.pyc in _pre_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    113         fit_params_steps = dict((step, {}) for step, _ in self.steps)
    114         for pname, pval in six.iteritems(fit_params):
--> 115             step, param = pname.split('__', 1)
    116             fit_params_steps[step][param] = pval
    117         Xt = X

ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I am using *`sklearn` version `0.14`*.
I think that the problem is that the `F selection` step in the pipeline does not take in an argument for sample_weights.  how do I pass this parameter to only one step in the pipeline with I run "`fit`"?  Thanks.

Comment: How is `m` defined in your second code sample? What is `general_pipeline` used for (it is defined but never used, it seems)? Furthermore, it would help if you also provided some data.

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy and paste error.

Comment: Ok, could you also show your input data?

Comment: I've provided much more information, and hopefully it is enough to reproduce the error.  Let me know if it is still not clear.  This is sort of urgent!  Thanks.

Comment: Why is `X` an object array with a string as the final item in each row?

Comment: It seems that `random_state` is not defined. How is it defined?

Comment: `random_state` can be anything it's just a random seed.  The final column can be converted to a float, and it is automatically in `sklearn`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[From the documentation:](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html)

> The purpose of the pipeline is to assemble several steps that can be
>   cross-validated together while setting different parameters. For this,
>   it enables setting parameters of the various steps **using their names
>   and the parameter name separated by a ‘__’**, as in the example below.

So you can simply insert `model__` in front of whatever fit parameter kwargs you want to pass to your `'model'` step:

```
m.fit(X, y, model__sample_weight=np.array([3,4,2,3]))
```

Comment: You were slightly faster. The second line is indeed the recommend one, it seems. You can also check [this link](https://sourceforge.net/p/scikit-learn/mailman/message/30266127/).

Comment: Hm. This doesn't work for me and gives the same error?

Comment: It works great for me (in both cases `m.predict(X)` returns `[0, 0, 0, 0]`).

Comment: @Sother: Are you sure that you use two underscores and not only one? If one uses only one, one indeed gets the same error. I am using 0.17; you should probably update...

Comment: There are some answers misleading me to `pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train, fit_params={'sample_weight': sample_weight})` until find this. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the method [`set_params`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.set_params) and prepend the name of the step.

```
m = sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline([
    ('feature_selection', sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest(
        score_func=sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression,
        k=25)),
    ('model', sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(
        random_state=0, 
        oob_score=True, 
        n_estimators=500,
        min_samples_leaf=5, 
        max_depth=10))])
```

```
m.set_params(model__sample_weight=np.array([3,4,2,3]))
```

Comment: This isn't correct. `set_params` is for *data-independent* hyperparameters (eg `max_depth`). `sample_weight` is data-dependent, AKA it will be different for each different X that is passed to `fit`. Therefore `sample_weight` needs to be passed during `fit()` as in @ali_m's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35634198/5156887

Answer (score 3):

Wish I could leave a comment on @rovyko post above instead of a separate answer but I don't have enough stackoverflow reputation yet to leave comments so here it is instead.

You cannot use:

`Pipeline.set_params(model__sample_weight=np.array([3,4,2,3])`

to set parameters for the `RandomForestClassifier.fit()` method. `Pipeline.set_params()` as indicated in the code ([here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b136e92acf49d46251479b75c88cba632de1937/sklearn/base.py#L191)) is only for initialization parameters for individual steps in the Pipeline. `RandomForestClassifier` has no initialization parameter called `sample_weight` (see its `__init__()` method [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b136e92acf49d46251479b75c88cba632de1937/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py#L996)). `sample_weight` is actually an input parameter to `RandomForestClassifier`'s `fit()` method and can therefore only be set by the method presented in the correctly marked answer be @ali_m, which is,

`m.fit(X, y, model__sample_weight=np.array([3,4,2,3]))`.

Comment: you can request an edit to an answer if you think it is wrong. Submit an edit to mine and I will accept the edit.

Comment: I have tried with my pipeline (a standardization followed by a regularized logistic regression classifier) using  mypipeline.fit(X_train, y_train, classifier__C=0.5) but it gives me this error: LogisticRegression.fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'C'.