# Sklearn pass fit() parameters to xgboost in pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, xgboost, keyword-argument

Similar to [How to pass a parameter to only one part of a pipeline object in scikit learn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35632634/how-to-pass-a-parameter-to-only-one-part-of-a-pipeline-object-in-scikit-learn) I want to pass parameters to only one part of a pipeline. Usually, it should work fine like:

```
estimator = XGBClassifier()
pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('clf', estimator)
    ])
```

and executed like

```
pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train, clf__early_stopping_rounds=20)
```

but it fails with:

```
    /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
        114         """
        115         Xt, yt, fit_params = self._pre_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    --> 116         self.steps[-1][-1].fit(Xt, yt, **fit_params)
        117         return self
        118 

    /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xgboost-0.6-py3.5.egg/xgboost/sklearn.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, eval_set, eval_metric, early_stopping_rounds, verbose)
        443                               early_stopping_rounds=early_stopping_rounds,
        444                               evals_result=evals_result, obj=obj, feval=feval,
    --> 445                               verbose_eval=verbose)
        446 
        447         self.objective = xgb_options["objective"]

    /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xgboost-0.6-py3.5.egg/xgboost/training.py in train(params, dtrain, num_boost_round, evals, obj, feval, maximize, early_stopping_rounds, evals_result, verbose_eval, learning_rates, xgb_model, callbacks)
        201                            evals=evals,
        202                            obj=obj, feval=feval,
    --> 203                            xgb_model=xgb_model, callbacks=callbacks)
        204 
        205 

    /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xgboost-0.6-py3.5.egg/xgboost/training.py in _train_internal(params, dtrain, num_boost_round, evals, obj, feval, xgb_model, callbacks)
         97                                end_iteration=num_boost_round,
         98                                rank=rank,
    ---> 99                                evaluation_result_list=evaluation_result_list))
        100         except EarlyStopException:
        101             break

    /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xgboost-0.6-py3.5.egg/xgboost/callback.py in callback(env)
        196     def callback(env):
        197         """internal function"""
    --> 198         score = env.evaluation_result_list[-1][1]
        199         if len(state) == 0:
        200             init(env)

    IndexError: list index out of range
```

Whereas a

```
estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, early_stopping_rounds=20)
```

works just fine.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For the early stopping rounds, you must always specify the validation set given by the argument eval_set. Here is how the error in your code can be fixed.

```
pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train, clf__early_stopping_rounds=20, clf__eval_set=[(test_X, test_y)])
```

Comment: Wondering what's the best practice when the pipeline includes, say, StandardScaler. Or columns removal. test_X won't undergo required changes in current case. Oh, it's already answered below.

Answer (score 14):

I recently used the following steps to use the eval metric and eval_set parameters for Xgboost.

### 1. create the pipeline with the pre-processing/feature transformation steps:

#### This was made from a pipeline defined earlier which includes the xgboost model as the last step.

```
pipeline_temp = pipeline.Pipeline(pipeline.cost_pipe.steps[:-1])
```

### 2. Fit this Pipeline

```
X_trans = pipeline_temp.fit_transform(X_train[FEATURES],y_train)
```

### 3. Create your eval_set by applying the transformations to the test set

```
eval_set = [(X_trans, y_train), (pipeline_temp.transform(X_test), y_test)]
```

### 4. Add your xgboost step back into the Pipeline

```
 pipeline_temp.steps.append(pipeline.cost_pipe.steps[-1])
```

### 5. Fit the new pipeline by passing the Parameters

```
pipeline_temp.fit(X_train[FEATURES], y_train,
             xgboost_model__eval_metric = ERROR_METRIC,
             xgboost_model__eval_set = eval_set)
```

### 6. Persist the Pipeline if you wish to.

```
joblib.dump(pipeline_temp, save_path)
```

Comment: This seems like the best possible solution among all the answers posted.

Comment: This is not working with the version 0.23.2 of scikit-learn

Comment: Hey @ucsky, can you suggest which specific part of the code from above does not work ?

Comment: Great answer, but it seems that second fit() call at step 5 will repeat all the computations from step 2. Any way to save them? Maybe we can replace step 2 with fit_transform, and save the output as X_train_processed,Y_train_processed, and at step 5 use them instead of original X and y?

Comment: You are right Anatoly. I modified the code to skip this repeated computation. I did it by fitting the last step manually and skipping step 5. I cannot put my code in a pretty way as a reply, so I post it as another answer

Answer (score 8):

This is the solution: https://www.kaggle.com/c/otto-group-product-classification-challenge/forums/t/13755/xgboost-early-stopping-and-other-issues both early_stooping_rounds and the watchlist / eval_set need to be passed. Unfortunately, this does not work for me, as the variables on the watchlist would require a preprocessing step which is only applied in the pipeline / I would need to apply this step manually.

Comment: I think it would be better if you un-accepted this answer. Your question is basically 'how do I do [x] in an sklearn pipeline' and the answer you link to does not use an sklearn pipeline. and you even say in your answer you accepted that "this does not work for" you because of that. If someone did come along with an answer for how to do this in a pipeline, it would be better that that be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that works in a Pipeline with GridSearchCV:

**Over-ride the XGBRegressor or XGBClssifier.fit() Function**

- This step uses train_test_split() to select the specified number of
  validation records from X for the eval_set and then passes the
  remaining records along to fit().
- A new parameter eval_test_size is added to .fit() to control the number of validation records. (see train_test_split [test_size](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) documenation)
- **kwargs passes along any other parameters added by the user for the XGBRegressor.fit() function.

```
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

class XGBRegressor_ES(XGBRegressor):
    
    def fit(self, X, y, *, eval_test_size=None, **kwargs):
        
        if eval_test_size is not None:
        
            params = super(XGBRegressor, self).get_xgb_params()
            
            X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
                X, y, test_size=eval_test_size, random_state=params['random_state'])
            
            eval_set = [(X_test, y_test)]
            
            # Could add (X_train, y_train) to eval_set 
            # to get .eval_results() for both train and test
            #eval_set = [(X_train, y_train),(X_test, y_test)] 
            
            kwargs['eval_set'] = eval_set
            
        return super(XGBRegressor_ES, self).fit(X_train, y_train, **kwargs)
```

**Example Usage**

Below is a multistep pipeline that includes multiple transformations to X. The pipeline's fit() function passes the new evaluation parameter to the XGBRegressor_ES class above as xgbr__eval_test_size=200.  In this example:

- X_train contains text documents passed to the pipeline.
- XGBRegressor_ES.fit() uses train_test_split() to select 200 records from X_train for the validation set and early stopping. (This could also be a percentage such as xgbr__eval_test_size=0.2)
- The remaining records in X_train are passed along to XGBRegressor.fit() for the actual fit().
- Early stopping may now occur after 75 rounds of unchanged boosting for each cv fold in a gridsearch.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectPercentile, f_regression
   
xgbr_pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
                     ('vt',VarianceThreshold()),
                     ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
                     ('Sp', SelectPercentile()),
                     ('xgbr',XGBRegressor_ES(n_estimators=2000,
                                             objective='reg:squarederror',
                                             eval_metric='mae',
                                             learning_rate=0.0001,
                                             random_state=7))    ])

X_train = train_idxs['f_text'].values
y_train = train_idxs['Pct_Change_20'].values
```

**Example Fitting the Pipeline:**

```
%time xgbr_pipe.fit(X_train, y_train, 
                    xgbr__eval_test_size=200,
                    xgbr__eval_metric='mae', 
                    xgbr__early_stopping_rounds=75)
```

**Example Fitting GridSearchCV:**

```
learning_rate = [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
param_grid = dict(xgbr__learning_rate=learning_rate)

grid_search = GridSearchCV(xgbr_pipe, param_grid, scoring="neg_mean_absolute_error", n_jobs=-1, cv=10)
grid_result = grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train, 
                    xgbr__eval_test_size=200,
                    xgbr__eval_metric='mae', 
                    xgbr__early_stopping_rounds=75)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a pipeline like:

```py
pipeline = Pipeline([('preprocessor', preprocessor), ('model', xgboost_model)])
```

You can use this function to pass `eval_set` to the `model.fit` step:

```py
def pipeline_fit_with_eval_set(pipeline, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, fit_params={}):
    """
    Fit a scikit-learn pipeline with eval_set support.

    Parameters:
    - pipeline: The scikit-learn pipeline.
    - X_train: Training data.
    - y_train: Training labels.
    - X_test: Test data.
    - y_test: Test labels.
    - fit_params: Additional fit parameters.
    - pipeline_model_step_name: Name of the model step in the pipeline.

    Usage:
    pipeline_fit_with_eval_set(my_pipeline, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, fit_params={'eval_metric': 'logloss'})
    """
    # Step 1: Extract Preprocessors
    pipeline_preprocessors = Pipeline(pipeline.steps[:-1])
    
    # Step 2: Fit preprocessors and Transform Training Data
    # Make sure not to use any test data for the fit step
    X_train_transformed = pipeline_preprocessors.fit_transform(X_train)

    # Step 3: Transform Test Data
    X_test_transformed = pipeline_preprocessors.transform(X_test)

    # Step 4: Prepare Eval Set
    fit_params["eval_set"] = [(X_test_transformed, y_test)]

    # Step 5: Extract Model and Fit
    model = pipeline.steps[-1][1]
    model.fit(X_train_transformed, y_train, **fit_params)
```

I was initially inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55711752/4276151) and improved it.
You can use this function for any other model that needs `eval_set` such as `LightGBM` and `CatBoost`.