# How can I use LGBM early stopping rounds parameters in a Scikit-Learn pipeline?

Tags: python, nlp, pipeline, countvectorizer

I've been trying this for a while, but still couldn't figure out the solution.

I have a pipeline with a few steps and a LGBM classifier, which I want to use with early_stopping_round parameter. However, I keep getting errors regarding this parameter. This was my last try:

```
model = lgb.LGBMClassifier(
    class_weight={0: class_weights[0], 1: class_weights[1]},
    early_stopping_round=50,
    eval_metric="logloss",
    learning_rate=0.1,
)

pipe = Pipeline(
    [
        ("vect",CountVectorizer(),),
        ("feature_sel", SelectKBest(chi2, k=200)),
        ("model", model),
    ]
)


pipe.fit(
    X_train,
    y_train,
    model__eval_set=[X_test, y_test],
)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

print(f"Accuracy: {accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred):.3f}")
print(f"F1-score: {f1_score(y_test, y_pred):.3f}")
print(f"Recall-score: {recall_score(y_test, y_pred):.3f}")
print(f"Precision-score: {precision_score(y_test, y_pred):.3f}")
print(f"ROC AUC: {roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred):.3f}")
print(f"Logloss: {log_loss(y_test, y_pred):.3f}")
```

I got this error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I already tried some insights from these discussions: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40329576/sklearn-pass-fit-parameters-to-xgboost-in-pipeline), [this](https://www.kaggle.com/questions-and-answers/101994), [this](https://www.kaggle.com/questions-and-answers/115480) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56346632/xgboost-cannot-pass-validation-data-for-eval-set-in-pipeline). Nothing seem to work for my case. Any idea?

It's a pretty common dataset, I've been trying this pipeline in the [spam dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/uciml/sms-spam-collection-dataset/code) from Kaggle.