# Keras model in Scikit-learn pipeline with early stopping

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, pipeline

I'm training a Keras model which sits in a Scikit pipeline with some preprocessing. The Keras model is defined as

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline


def create_model(X_train):
    inp = Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1],))
    x = Dense(150, activation="relu")(inp)
    x = Dropout(0.4)(x)
    mean = Dense(1, activation="linear")(x)
    train_model_1 = Model(inp, mean)
    adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01)
    train_model_1.compile(loss=my_loss_function, optimizer=adam)
    return train_model_1


clf = KerasRegressor(build_fn=create_model, epochs=250, batch_size=64)
```

Which is then used in a `Pipeline` with

```
pipeline = make_pipeline(
                other_steps,
                clf(X_train)
            )


pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I want to use `EarlyStopping` where the test data (`X_test, y_test`) is used to validate against. This would normally be straightforward with

```
callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5)]

train_model_1.fit(X_train, y_train,
                  validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
                  callbacks=callbacks,
                  )
```

But I can't figure out where this would go in the pipeline. What is the right way to structure this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Pipeline.fit`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.fit) has a keyword-argument parameter:

> ****fit_params : *dict of string -> object***
>
> Parameters passed to the fit method of each step, where each parameter name is prefixed such that parameter `p` for step `s` has key `s__p`.

So something like `pipeline.fit(x_train, y_train, kerasregressor__callbacks=callbacks)` should work.  (Check the name of your pipeline steps, e.g. with `pipeline.steps`; `make_pipeline` generates the names using the lowercased name of the class, but I'm not sure offhand whether that'll work right with `keras`.)

See also [How to pass a parameter to only one part of a pipeline object in scikit learn?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35632634/10495893)